# Flat File Destination Failed the pre-execute phase. Cannot open the datafile

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, ssis, etl

I am executing a SSIS Package from a C# WinForm project.  It executes and runs about halfway when it tries to create/write a file (An Expression in the Flat File Manager).

When I check the SSISDB Catalog on the SQL Server, I see the following errors for the package:

> Flat File Destination failed the pre-execute phase and returned error
> code 0xC020200E.
>
> PO Header:Error: Cannot open the datafile "\Server\path\Admin Shared
> Folders\Information
> Systems\Projects\projectPath\filepath\636943168325507712-1070-15175.txt".

Based on the path and filename, the expression resolved fine.  When I run the SSIS package directly it runs fine, so it appears to be a permission issue.

I am using Integration Services (MS SQL Server 2014) and right now I am using windows authentication in my connect string:

```
Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

However, the group who will be using the app will not have full permissions, so a specific user account will be created in SQL Server that I will use to connect.  That said, assuming that this is a permission issue, how does the SQL Server account need to be created / what permissions and considerations need to be applied?  What other permission issues/considerations need to be taken into account?

ie, we have no idea how to create the account to make this work and need help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are ask for run with SQL agent and hit permission issue, you can do this, in Windows service there are a service name call SQL Server Agent, and Log on with a special account, likely you create a individual account, and give this account to your folder permission.

Comment: No, I am using IntegrationServices to call the package via the SSISDB catalog

Comment: SQL Agent also call IntegrationServices.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that SQL service account can access to this path and has needed permissions:

- [Configure File System Permissions for Database Engine Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-file-system-permissions-for-database-engine-access?view=sql-server-2017)